# Save a value from Google Tag manager DataLayer in a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Iam using Google Tag manager==GTM as well as Visual Website Optimizer==VWO. All the script tags for both application are implemented accordingly.

In order to be able to track revenue we have to save the transactionTotal of an order into a variable that VWO uses to count the conversion rates on a specific test. The VWO clicks and visits are counted correctly but not the conversion.

I have created a macro in GTM ({transactionTotal}) based on fetching the data.

1. First I get all the meta tags where we have the ecommerce values.

   var metaObj = {}, m = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'), i = m.length; //scope expanded from only .head
       while (i--) { // looping down will result in the same behaviour as stopping @ 1st
           metaObj[m[i].name] = m[i].content;
       }
2. Then push the meta value in the dataLayer

   dataLayer.push({'transactionId': metaObj['WT.tx_i']});
3. In GTM I created a macro [image: GTM macro]
4. in the confirmation page:

   //should be the value of the order total
   var _vis_opt_revenue = ({transactionTotal});

This returns an error and no value is save in this variable.

Any ideas or help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I had a syntax error user parenthesis instead of curly brackets

so it should be

```
var _vis_opt_revenue = {{transactionTotal}};
```

instead of

`var _vis_opt_revenue = ({transactionTotal});`

Answer (score 0):

Could you indent your code please ? It will be much easier.

Secondly, you use a macro that is looking for
transactionTotal
and you push on dataLayer an object named
transactionId
Therefore, it could not work